# How to check if Firefox extension code is running in privileged mode?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I have some event dispatching/listening going on between a Firefox extension and page content.
Page content code is injected in extension's on-content-page-load handler.

Is there a way I could check what mode is the current piece of code running (privileged mode or not privileged mode)?

Comment: One thing I tried is evaluating `window.location.href` and checking if it matches `chrome://browser...` but that doesn't seem to be a definite indicator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical approach is checking whether you can access [`Components.classes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Components.classes):

```
try {
  Components.classes;
  alert("Yay! Privileged code.");
}
catch (e) {
  alert("Oops... Content privileges only.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the environment:

Within an addon-sdk addon you could check for `require` or `exports`:

```
if(typeof(require)!=="undefined" && typeof(exports)!=="undefined"){
  //privileged
}
```

(note: typeof is used to prevent errors when checking for variable existence.)

---

else check for `Components` (or `Cc, Ci, Cu`) as Wladimir suggested.

---

or even check to see if a xul:window element exists:

```
var xulWindow=document.querySelector("window#main-window[windowtype='navigator:browser']");
if(xulWindow){
  //privileged. in this case looking specifically for "navigator:browser" windowtype.
}
```